# How can I use require and import both in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, import, require, express-router

This is my server.js file:

```js
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Connect Database
connectDB();

// Init Middleware
app.use(express.json());

// Define Routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'));
```

In this code, I have some problem like following.

```
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module E:\Study\DEC\devconnector_mobang\config\db.js from E:\Study\DEC\devconnector_mobang\index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of db.js in E:\Study\DEC\devconnector_mobang\index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

This error 's reason is just require.
So I hope to use both import and require or convert require into import.
I have strived the some way.

```js
import express from "express";
import connectDB from "./config/db.js";
import path from "path";

// Define require
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

const app = express();

// Connect Database
connectDB();

// Init Middleware
app.use(express.json());

const user = require("./config/default");

app.use("/api/users", user);
```

In here, it can't read this.

```
import connectDB from "./config/db.js";
```

But it can read this.

```
import connectDB from "./config/default.json";
```

I hope to help you for me to this problem.
Thanks.

I hope to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this problem solved.
This problem is depended node version.
Node 16 and Node 20 is definitely different.
My node used version 20.
I change it version 16 using nvm.
Npm install is success and require is normal.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you can use both import and require in a node project but **not in the same file**.
For example if you are using `type: commonjs` then you can add extension `.mjs` to  import modules in that file.

But if you are using `type: module` then you can import and use `createRequire` method:

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

// Now you can use require
const express = require('express');
```

Comment: I hope to use this code.
import connectDB from "./config/db.js";

Comment: I need help of expert.

Comment: This answer is described way in my code.     And it use both import and require in one file.